# Restrict features when user is running old version of application, only if there are changes to the online engine

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to restrict online gaming features inside an application, ONLY when there is an update available which impacts the online game code/engine. I know I can disable the online gaming features if the string in `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]` (referenced from question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749842/check-and-update-an-application-through-code-when-a-new-version-is-available-in)) is not equal to the most recent version in the app store. But if I release an update that does not impact the online gaming experience I do not want to disable the online features.

Does anybody have a creative way to "tag" a release so that I can detect whether the update has an impact to online gaming? Would adding a subversion be the best way? I.E. updates with online features change subversion level 2 (1.2.1) and non-online updates change subversion level 3 (1.1.2)?

As a note, I disable the online gaming features when updates are available in case the update has changes to how a packet is sent or a fix to the scoring engine etc.. so I don't encounter a scenario where an old version is playing a new version and the messages don't match up. (I have also considered using Game Center Groups to make sure you are playing a player from the same app version, but ultimately decided that getting users to upgrade is a better plan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this by having a list of valid versions on the server in the form of a whitelist.  When checking if the user can be online (for example, when they hit the Multiplayer button), just ping your server including the user's bundle version and have the server return a simple response which denotes whether the user can play based on the version number that they submitted.

I do something relatively similar on an application of mine to push actual code updates to a client based on the version of the application that they are running.

Comment: I like the whitelist idea, but was hoping for something tricky without having to check with the server, Thanks Aaron!